# Correct format for AWS CloudWatch

Tags: haskell, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, servant

I use [Servant](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server) and [colog](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/co-log) in a Docker container which runs on AWS ECS.

The HTTP requests are perfectly logged into AWS CloudWatch but not my manual logging.

I have initiated my WAI server that way:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  withStdoutLogger $ \aplogger -> do
    let settings = setPort 8080 $ setLogger aplogger defaultSettings
    initializeApplication >>= runSettings settings
```

I also have tried to imitate the Apache Logging style with:

```
logStringStdoutCloudWatch :: MonadIO m => LogAction m String
logStringStdoutCloudWatch = LogAction $ \x -> liftIO $ do
  let format = "%d/%b/%Y:%T %z"
  time <- getCurrentTime
  putStrLn $ "- - - [" ++ formatTime defaultTimeLocale format time ++ "] \"log\" - - \"\" \"" ++ x ++ "\""
```

It gives me the  following logs:

```
- - - [12/Nov/2020:16:36:16 +0000] "log" - - "" "A log message"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2020:17:36:16 +0100] "POST /event HTTP/1.1" 400 - "" "Client"
```

But only the last line is logged in CloudWatch.

What is wrong with my formatting? Alternatively: is there dedicated lib/function to have the correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have cheated changing the log format to json, first at `Servant` level:

```
import Network.Wai.Middleware
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger.JSON(formatAsJSONWithHeaders)

initializeApplication :: IO Application
initializeApplication = do
  logger <- 
  mkRequestLogger def {outputFormat = CustomOutputFormatWithDetailsAndHeaders formatAsJSONWithHeaders}
  return
    $ logger
    $ serve (Proxy @API)
    $ hoistServer (Proxy @API) (toHandler env) server

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let settings = setPort 8080 defaultSettings
  initializeApplication >>= runSettings settings
```

and the logger:

```
logStringStdoutCloudWatch :: MonadIO m => LogAction m String
logStringStdoutCloudWatch = LogAction $ \x -> liftIO $ do
  let format = "%d/%b/%Y:%T %z"
  time <- getCurrentTime
  putStrLn $ "{\"time\":\"" ++ formatTime defaultTimeLocale format time ++ "\",\"log\":\"" ++ x ++ "\"}"
```